Tag typo only appears in specific place
I'm in the tag page, the tags are sorted by popularity, and technic is one of them, as you can see here.

However, If I go to page seven, I see a typo in the tag name.

Hmm, strange. That typo doesn't appear on the first page, and also it does have questions asked with this tag. What's stranger is that all the surrounding tags also have "0 questions" but they do have questions, which I think is SE's fault. Also, it shows the real tag info if I hover over it.
But I'm not focused on that.

So is this odd typo the fault of Stack Exchange, or did someone here make an oopsie? I think it's the first one, right?

All tags are suggested and created by us users, rather than being forced upon us by Stack Exchange ;)

@Zhaph-BenDugid That's not what I meant. I meant that someone merged it or something and that the Stack Exchange database didn't sync or something, or maybe someone forgot about it.

Yes, I merged them back in 2014 - you can see this from the All Synonyms page. This is feature of the site - all synonyms behave like this - if you go to the last couple of pages of the "popular tags", you'll see all the "empty" tags that are mostly synonyms.

Somebody made an oopsie, but it has been corrected by making techinc a synonym of technic: see https://bricks.stackexchange.com/tags/technic/synonyms.

This often happens with misspelled tags; retagging would work too, but somebody else is bound to make the same mistake again. The synonym will help them find the correct tag, instead of creating a new one (if they have the 150 reputation to do so) or wondering why they can't find the one they want (surely, there must be a tag for Lego Techinc, right?)

Indeed we could burn it, but it's likely to come back again at some point, so often easier to keep them around as synonyms.

@Zhaph-BenDuguid: You need a certain reputation to create tags and you should get a warning that you are about to create a tag, so the risk should be rather low. Also note that you can merge the tags, so it does not say techinc on some question.

@Wrzlprmft True, it's less likely to come back now that we're out of beta, and running at full rep - it was probably created when the requirements to create tags were lower - but someone must have created it, even with those warnings for me to create the synonym back in 2014...

@Zhaph-BenDuguid until you have a design, you're still using the beta privilege levels ...
